# Error 0x800f0922 installing .NET 3.5 on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, .net-framework, .net-3.5

I'm trying to install .NET 3.5 on my Windows 8 box and it keeps throwing Error 0x800f0922 at me. From what I've read on answers.microsoft.com and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897326/redistributable-offline-net-framework-3-5-installer-for-windows-8) I gather the easiest way to fix this is to perform a system refresh, however this will remove all software I've installed from discs. I've just moved house, so I'd rather not do that as I don't know where all the installation media actually are for a lot of my software, so if possible I'd prefer to track down where the problem is actually occurring. (Also, I have a LOT of software installed. It'd take me a long time to reinstall it all, and I unfortunately haven't got that time.)

The on-demand error screen sends me to [KB2734782](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2734782), which doesn't help much.

When I run this DISM line from the StackOverflow post:

```
Dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:C:\Windows\WinSxS /LimitAccess
```

I get the following output on the terminal:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>Dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:C:\Windows\WinSxS /LimitAccess

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.2.9200.16384

Image Version: 6.2.9200.16384

Enabling feature(s)
[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 0x800f0922

DISM failed. No operation was performed.
For more information, review the log file.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Incidentally, it jumps straight from 0 to 100% and then sits on that line for about 5 minutes before the error line occurs.

dism.log contains the following lines around that time: (Link to full logs is at bottom of post)

```
2013-07-02 00:56:58, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: Edition Manager.
2013-07-02 00:56:58, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5768 TID=5780 Getting Provider DISM Package Manager - CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider
2013-07-02 00:56:58, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=5768 TID=5780 Provider has previously been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
2013-07-02 00:56:58, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5768 TID=5780 Processing the top level command token(enable-feature). - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ValidateCmdLine
2013-07-02 00:56:58, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5768 TID=5780 Attempting to route to appropriate command handler. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2013-07-02 00:56:58, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5768 TID=5780 Routing the command... - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2013-07-02 00:56:58, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5768 TID=5780 Encountered the option "featurename" with value "NetFX3" - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetPackagesFromCommandLine
2013-07-02 00:56:58, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5768 TID=5780 Encountered an unknown option "featurename" with value "NetFX3" - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetPackagesFromCommandLine
2013-07-02 00:56:58, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5768 TID=5780 Encountered the option "source" with value "C:\Windows\WinSxS" - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetPackagesFromCommandLine
2013-07-02 00:56:58, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5768 TID=5780 Encountered an unknown option "source" with value "C:\Windows\WinSxS" - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetPackagesFromCommandLine
2013-07-02 00:56:59, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5768 TID=5780 Initiating Changes on Package with values: 5, 7 - CDISMPackage::Internal_ChangePackageState
2013-07-02 00:56:59, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5768 TID=5780 CBS session options=0x20100! - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
2013-07-02 01:00:27, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5768 TID=2420  Error in operation: (null) (CBS HRESULT=0x800f0922) - CCbsConUIHandler::Error
2013-07-02 01:00:27, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5768 TID=5780 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x800f0922)
2013-07-02 01:00:27, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5768 TID=5780 Failed processing package changes with session options - CDISMPackageManager::ProcessChangesWithOptions(hr:0x800f0922)
2013-07-02 01:00:27, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5768 TID=5780 Failed ProcessChanges. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ProcessFeatureChange(hr:0x800f0922)
2013-07-02 01:00:27, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5768 TID=5780 Failed while processing command enable-feature. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x800f0922)
2013-07-02 01:00:27, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=5768 TID=5780 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2013-07-02 01:00:27, Error                 DISM   DISM.EXE: DISM Package Manager processed the command line but failed. HRESULT=800F0922
```

cbs.log has the following chunks around then which could be relevant:

```
2013-07-02 00:55:06, Info                  CBS    Exec: This is a PSF Package.  Job has been saved and we are returning to client.
2013-07-02 00:55:06, Info                  CSI    0000042d@2013/7/1:23:55:06.203 CSI Transaction @0xe2f5e59500 destroyed
2013-07-02 00:55:06, Info                  CBS    Exec: DPX job state saved for one or more packages, aborting the staging and install of execution.
2013-07-02 00:55:06, Info                  CSI    0000042e@2013/7/1:23:55:06.207 CSI Transaction @0xe2f5e58480 destroyed
2013-07-02 00:55:06, Info                  CBS    Perf: Stage chain complete.
2013-07-02 00:55:06, Info                  CBS    Failed to stage execution chain. [HRESULT = 0x800f0816 - CBS_E_DPX_JOB_STATE_SAVED]
2013-07-02 00:55:06, Info                  CBS    Failed to process single phase execution. [HRESULT = 0x800f0816 - CBS_E_DPX_JOB_STATE_SAVED]
2013-07-02 00:55:06, Info                  CBS    WER: Failure is not worth reporting [HRESULT = 0x800f0816 - CBS_E_DPX_JOB_STATE_SAVED]
2013-07-02 00:55:06, Info                  CBS    Reboot mark cleared
```

and further down:

```
2013-07-02 00:59:19, Info                  CSI    000004e6 Begin executing advanced installer phase 38 (0x00000026) index 253 (0x00000000000000fd) (sequence 289)
    Old component: [l:0]""
    New component: [ml:306{153},l:304{152}]"NetFx35CDF-CDF_GenericCommands, Culture=neutral, Version=6.2.9200.16384, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=x86, versionScope=NonSxS"
    Install mode: install
    Installer ID: {81a34a10-4256-436a-89d6-794b97ca407c}
    Installer name: [15]"Generic Command"
2013-07-02 00:59:19, Info                  CSI    000004e7 Performing 1 operations; 1 are not lock/unlock and follow:
  (0)  LockComponentPath (10): flags: 0 comp: {l:16 b:19fc6600b776ce01c91f0000fc07a816} pathid: {l:16 b:19fc6600b776ce01ca1f0000fc07a816} path: [l:214{107}]"\SystemRoot\WinSxS\x86_netfx35cdf-cdf_genericcommands_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_none_0cec490be12fb858" pid: 7fc starttime: 130171962799582915 (0x01ce76b5e2626ec3)
2013-07-02 00:59:19, Info                  CSI    000004e8 Performing 1 operations; 1 are not lock/unlock and follow:
  (0)  LockComponentPath (10): flags: 0 comp: {l:16 b:27236700b776ce01cb1f0000fc07a816} pathid: {l:16 b:27236700b776ce01cc1f0000fc07a816} path: [l:210{105}]"\SystemRoot\WinSxS\x86_netfx35cdf-csd_cdf_installer_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_none_55072425fd5c3716" pid: 7fc starttime: 130171962799582915 (0x01ce76b5e2626ec3)
2013-07-02 00:59:19, Info                  CSI    000004e9 Calling generic command executable (sequence 1): [122]"C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_netfx35cdf-csd_cdf_installer_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_none_55072425fd5c3716\WFServicesReg.exe"
    CmdLine: [139]""C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_netfx35cdf-csd_cdf_installer_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_none_55072425fd5c3716\WFServicesReg.exe" /c /b /v /m /i"
2013-07-02 00:59:20, Info                  CSI    000004ea Performing 1 operations; 1 are not lock/unlock and follow:
  (0)  LockComponentPath (10): flags: 0 comp: {l:16 b:bd790401b776ce01cd1f0000fc07a816} pathid: {l:16 b:bd790401b776ce01ce1f0000fc07a816} path: [l:234{117}]"\SystemRoot\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.s..ation.badcomponents_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_none_353ccb4c94858655" pid: 7fc starttime: 130171962799582915 (0x01ce76b5e2626ec3)
2013-07-02 00:59:20, Info                  CSI    000004eb Creating NT transaction (seq 27), objectname [6]"(null)"
2013-07-02 00:59:20, Info                  CSI    000004ec Created NT transaction (seq 27) result 0x00000000, handle @0x24b8
2013-07-02 00:59:20, Info                  CSI    000004ed@2013/7/1:23:59:20.933 Beginning NT transaction commit...
2013-07-02 00:59:22, Info                  CSI    000004ee@2013/7/1:23:59:22.065 CSI    perf trace:
CSIPERF:TXCOMMIT;1387723
2013-07-02 00:59:22, Error                 CSI    000004ef (F) Done with generic command 1; CreateProcess returned 0, CPAW returned S_OK
    Process exit code 255 (0x000000ff) resulted in success? FALSE
    Process output: [l:28479 [4096]"DDSet_Entry: WFServicesReg.exe
DDSet_Status: CFxInstaller::CopyConfigFilesToTemp is64bit=0
DDSet_Status: CFileHelper::CopyConfigFilesToTempLocation
DDSet_Status: CFxInstaller::SetupBaseComponents isInstall=1
DDSet_Status: CFxInstaller::SetupBaseComponents Calling SetupExtensions. isInstall=1
```

(0x000000FF -- The extended attributes are inconsistent. ??)

And a bit further down:

```
2013-07-02 00:59:22, Error      [0x018007] CSI    000004f0 (F) Failed execution of queue item Installer: Generic Command ({81a34a10-4256-436a-89d6-794b97ca407c}) with HRESULT HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(14109).  Failure will not be ignored: A rollback will be initiated after all the operations in the installer queue are completed; installer is reliable (2)[gle=0x80004005]
[...snip...]
2013-07-02 00:59:22, Info                  CBS    Not able to add pending.xml.bad to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2013-07-02 00:59:28, Info                  CSI    000004f1@2013/7/1:23:59:28.467 CSI Advanced installer perf trace:
CSIPERF:AIDONE;{81a34a10-4256-436a-89d6-794b97ca407c};NetFx35CDF-CDF_GenericCommands, Version = 6.2.9200.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral;10609242us
2013-07-02 00:59:28, Info                  CSI    000004f2 End executing advanced installer (sequence 289)
    Completion status: HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_ADVANCED_INSTALLER_FAILED) 
[...snip...]
2013-07-02 01:00:26, Info                  CBS    Exec: Cancelled pending transactions after rollback. [HRESULT = 0x00000000 - S_OK]
2013-07-02 01:00:26, Error                 CBS    Exec: An error occurred while committing the transaction, the transaction could not be rolled back. [HRESULT = 0x800f0922 - CBS_E_INSTALLERS_FAILED]
```

The full DISM and CBS logs are at http://ben.mu/files/dotnet35_dism_cbs.zip as the CBS log is nearly 167MB uncompressed. o.o dism.log gives the timeframe of where its errors occur--00:56:20ish to 01:00:22.

Does anyone have any ideas what's actually causing the installation to fail, and if so how I can fix it? Please don't just say "Refresh the OS". :)

Answer (score 1):

Your source parameter is wrong. The files are removed from C:\Windows\WinSxS. You must point to the SxS folder on your mounted ISO/DVDdrive/USB thumb drive:

```
Dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:DRIVELETTER:\sources\SxS /LimitAccess
```

**Installing the .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443.aspx

Comment: Hmm... I've re-downloaded the ISO image, and I'm now running the DISM installation using F:\sources\SxS, however I'm still getting the same straight-to-100%-then-fail problem as above. I'll check the dism.log file again and upload it if necessary.

Comment: From dism.log:  
  
Encountered the option "featurename" with value "NetFX3" - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetPackagesFromCommandLine  
Encountered an unknown option "featurename" with value "NetFX3" - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetPackagesFromCommandLine  
Encountered the option "source" with value "F:\sources\SxS" - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetPackagesFromCommandLine  
Encountered an unknown option "source" with value "F:\sources\SxS" - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetPackagesFromCommandLine  
  
Any ideas why they're being flagged as unknown options?

Comment: upload the newest log (all files from CBS and the DISM.log)

Comment: The logs are identical to the ones above save for the timestamps, but I've done some more Googling and apparently the 0x800f0922 error occurs when you've installed language packs before installing .NET 3.5. (See: <http://munnamark.blogspot.com/2012/11/dot-net-framework-35-not-installing-on.html>) Unfortunately, they don't seem to know of a way to fix it without performing a system refresh. :/

Comment: There is this line in there shortly before the HRESULT=0x800F0922 is triggered: `Process output: [l:209 [209]"SMConfigInstaller[Error]: Opening file 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\web.config' failed. Error code: 0x80070002` Seems to be related?

Comment: can you please uninstall the language pack, install .net 3.5 and install the MUI again? Does this work?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the behaviour as follows.

Adding the feature ".NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)" through the control panel fails when in a domain using WSUS.

Running the following command, as Administrator, against the original installation media also fails **when a language pack is installed**, English in my case on a German installation.

```
Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /All /Source:x:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
```

The error here is the same as the OP mentioned. "Source not found" normally around the 65% mark.

Also, its not enough to simply switch back to the original language. The installed language pack must be uninstalled and the system rebooted.

After this the above command runs successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

Use the command prompt with admin privileges, then type:

```
net stop wuauserv
net stop cryptSvc
net stop bits
net stop msiserver
ren c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution sd1.old
ren c:\windows\system32\catroot2 catroot.old
net start wuauserv
net start cryptSvc
net start bits
net start msiserver
```

After doing this, try a reinstall.